# Delphi XE8 TBindSourceDB component using MasterSource

Tags: delphi, data-binding, sql-insert, firemonkey

The question is what is the correctly usage of MasterSource for TBindSourceDB
Ex.

1 ListView with departaments with a navigator linkeds to a TBindSourceDB (the master).
When navigator Insert button is pressed another listview becomes active, the cities ListView.
Now the cities ListView with another navigator links to another TBindSourceDB, the cities (the detail).
I need cities be mastersourced to departaments. How and where must do it?

Both, the master and detail TBindSourceDB are linked to Firedac TSimpleDataSet components which have MasterSource property. I've filled that property on detail pointing to master component.
The problem is: when the "detail" navigator button insert is pressed , the OnBeforePost from TSimpleDataSet fires, because it wants to do a Post!! and not fires the OnAfterInsert event.
Which is the correct mode for work master->detail data with Firemonkey and TBindSourceDB components?.

Comment: TSimpleDataSet is a component for the DBExpress library, not FireDAC, so are you actually asking about DBExpress or FireDAC ?

Comment: Yes, excuse me. TSimpleDataSet is dbExpress, I was testing with TFDQuery before

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I think the project below will
show you the most important things about adding Master + Detail records. I think
the TListViews are actually a distraction from understanding what's needed, so
I'm going to leave them out and instead use some TEdits to display the Master
+ Details records a row at a time.

In my experience a rule of thumb is to avoid doing something using LiveBindings
if there is a simpler way of doing it, and this is the case when it comes to
establishing the Master->Detail relationship between the Master and Details.

So, amongst the list of components on the form is a TDataSource which links the
two. Its DataSet property is connected to the Master; on the Detail's side
Detail's MasterSource property should be set to it and its MasterField property
is set to the Master's MasterID field.

The point of adding the TDataSource is that it enables you to use the standard
TDataset model and the events it supports to do all the work necessary to establish
the link between a new Detail record as it is inserted and the current MasterRecord.
This is done in the OnNewRecord event of the Detail, which reads like this:

```
procedure TMasterDetailForm.DetailNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Detail.FieldByName('DetailID').AsInteger := NextDetailID;
  Detail.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger := Master.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger;
  Detail.FieldByName('Name').AsString := Format('DetailID:%d for MasterID:%d ', [NextDetailID, Master.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger]);
  inc(NextDetailID);
end;
```

A benefit of using the TDataSource is that it guarantees that the Master and Detail are correctly
synchronised when a new Detail record is inserted.

The only other signficant code is in the FormCreate evnt, which is used to create and populate
the Master and Detail datasets with a few sample records.  All the LiveBindings connections
are set up when the form's DFM is loaded.  An extract of the DFM is below the project source code:

Code

```
unit MasterDetailListsu;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ListView.Types, Data.Bind.GenData,
  Fmx.Bind.GenData, System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt,
  Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope, FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListView, FMX.ListView.Appearances,
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.MultiView,FMX.Memo, Fmx.Bind.Navigator, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList,
  FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.TreeView, Data.Bind.DBScope, SimpleDS,
  Data.Bind.Controls, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Grid.Style, FMX.Grid, FMX.ScrollBox,
  FMX.Edit;

type
  TMasterDetailForm = class(TForm)
    Master: TSimpleDataSet;
    Detail: TSimpleDataSet;
    MasterMasterID: TIntegerField;
    MasterName: TStringField;
    DetailDetailID: TIntegerField;
    DetailMasterID: TIntegerField;
    DetailName: TStringField;
    BindSourceMaster: TBindSourceDB;
    NavigatorBindSourceDB1: TBindNavigator;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    BindGridLink1: TBindGridLink;
    edMasterID: TEdit;
    LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField;
    edMasterName: TEdit;
    LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField;
    edDetailID: TEdit;
    edDetailMasterID: TEdit;
    edDetailName: TEdit;
    LinkControlToField3: TLinkControlToField;
    BindSourceDetail: TBindSourceDB;
    LinkControlToField4: TLinkControlToField;
    BindNavigator1: TBindNavigator;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    LinkControlToField5: TLinkControlToField;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DetailNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure MasterNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
  private
  public
    NextMasterID,
    NextDetailID : Integer;
  end;

[...]

procedure TMasterDetailForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,
  j : Integer;
begin

  Master.IndexFieldNames := 'MasterID';
  Master.CreateDataSet;

  Detail.IndexFieldNames := 'MasterID;DetailID';
  Detail.CreateDataSet;

  NextMasterID := 1;
  NextDetailID := 1;

  for i := 1 to 3 do begin
    Master.Insert;
    Master.Post;
    for j := 1 to 3 do begin
      Detail.Insert;
      Detail.Post;
    end;
  end;

  Master.First;

end;

procedure TMasterDetailForm.DetailNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Detail.FieldByName('DetailID').AsInteger := NextDetailID;
  Detail.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger := Master.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger;
  Detail.FieldByName('Name').AsString := Format('DetailID:%d for MasterID:%d ', [NextDetailID, Master.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger]);
  inc(NextDetailID);
end;

procedure TMasterDetailForm.MasterNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Master.FieldByName('MasterID').AsInteger := NextMasterID;
  Master.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'Master' + IntToStr(NextMasterID);
  Inc(NextMasterID);
end;

end.
```

DFM extract

```
object MasterDetailForm: TMasterDetailForm
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  object NavigatorBindSourceDB1: TBindNavigator
    DataSource = BindSourceMaster
  end
  object edMasterID: TEdit
  end
  object edMasterName: TEdit
  end
  object edDetailID: TEdit
  end
  object edDetailMasterID: TEdit
  end
  object edDetailName: TEdit
  end
  object BindNavigator1: TBindNavigator
    DataSource = BindSourceDetail
  end
  object Master: TSimpleDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    DataSet.MaxBlobSize = -1
    DataSet.Params = <>
    MasterFields = 'MasterID'
    Params = <>
    OnNewRecord = MasterNewRecord
    Left = 64
    Top = 32
    object MasterMasterID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'MasterID'
    end
    object MasterName: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 30
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Size = 30
    end
  end
  object Detail: TSimpleDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    DataSet.MaxBlobSize = -1
    DataSet.Params = <>
    FieldDefs = <>
    IndexDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'DetailIndex1'
        Fields = 'MasterID;DetailID'
      end>
    IndexName = 'DetailIndex1'
    MasterFields = 'MasterID'
    MasterSource = DataSource1
    PacketRecords = 0
    Params = <>
    StoreDefs = True
    OnNewRecord = DetailNewRecord
    Left = 64
    Top = 224
    object DetailDetailID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'DetailID'
    end
    object DetailMasterID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'MasterID'
    end
    object DetailName: TStringField
      DisplayWidth = 30
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Size = 30
    end
  end
  object BindSourceMaster: TBindSourceDB
    DataSource.AutoEdit = False
    DataSet = Master
    ScopeMappings = <>
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    object BindGridLink1: TBindGridLink
      Category = 'Links'
      SourceComponent = Master
      ColumnExpressions = <
        item
          Name = 'Exp1'
          ColumnName = 'IDColumn'
          ColumnIndex = 0
          SourceMemberName = 'ID'
          ControlMemberName = 'IDColumn'
          ParseCellExpressions = <>
          FormatCellExpressions = <>
          FormatColumnExpressions = <>
        end>
      PosControlExpressions = <>
      PosSourceExpressions = <>
      FormatControlExpressions = <>
      ClearControlExpressions = <>
    end
    object LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceMaster
      FieldName = 'MasterID'
      Control = edMasterID
      Track = False
    end
    object LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceMaster
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Control = edMasterName
      Track = False
    end
    object LinkControlToField3: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceDetail
      FieldName = 'DetailID'
      Control = edDetailID
      Track = False
    end
    object LinkControlToField4: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceDetail
      FieldName = 'MasterID'
      Control = edDetailMasterID
      Track = False
    end
    object LinkControlToField5: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = BindSourceDetail
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Control = edDetailName
      Track = False
    end
  end
  object BindSourceDetail: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = Detail
    ScopeMappings = <>
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = Master
  end
end
```